# generics object creation showing error in eclipse, but compiles in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, generics, bounded-wildcard

Hi I have some initialization as below.... it is showing error in eclipse as type mismatch. if i compile using maven through command prompt, it compiles without any error.. using eclipse luna, and compiler set to java 1.7.

```
  ReportData<Object> rdata = null;

  rdata =  new ReportData<>(reportCtx.get()); // error shown for this line in //eclipse.

  ReportData<T>{

      private T val;
      public ReportData(T val){
          this.val=val;
      }
  }
```

I am not understanding, why eclipse show error for this and how it compiles in maven with the same java 1.7. whats wrong with `rdata = new ReportData<>(reportCtx.get());` initialization.

Comment: And what the error say?

Comment: error says Type mismatch: cannot convert from ReportData<capture#6-of ?> to ReportData<Object>

Comment: You can configure eclipse to display different things as errors warnings or ignore. Window > preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/warnings. Maybe that is why one works and the other not.

Comment: Than how about `rdata =  new ReportData<Object>(reportCtx.get());` ?

Comment: What is the signature of the method `reportCtx.get()`?

Comment: rdata = new ReportDat<Object>(reportCtx.get()) eliminates the error.

Comment: @Neilos the eclipse configuration is default one, and there is nothing configured as error for geneerics section. rdata = new ReportDat<Object>(reportCtx.get()) eliminates the error. but i want to know whats wrong with the previous way of initialization and what is the reason for this error.

Comment: @Duncan  reportCtx is of type Optional<?>. signature is T get();

Comment: The <> operator was, I thought, a bit of a syntax trick to do instantiation on the same line. E.g. `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()` - if you split it between lines, perhaps the compiler is less happy with the <> as there's less context to work with.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze I tried it with `ReportData<Object> rdata = new ReportData<>(reportCTx.get());` on one line. The error is the same.

Comment: Intesting - what does reportCTx.get() return?

Comment: @AshleyFrieze `reportCTx.get()` "returns" nothing at compile time. As it was mentioned earlier already it stands for a `T`. But that's not of interest here. It's about `ReportData.` Did you read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29170406/1744774)?

Answer (score 2):

`ReportData<?>` is the supertype of all kinds of report data.

`ReportData<Object>` is *not* the supertype of all kinds of report data.

Hence you cannot assign:

`ReportData<Object>` ← `ReportData<of an unknown kind>`

See [The Java™ Tutorials , Generics, Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

And BTW, in addition to ...

```
ReportData<Object> rdata = new ReportData<Object>(reportCtx.get());
```

... the different declaration in ...

```
ReportData<?> rdata = new ReportData<>(reportCtx.get());
```

... does the trick, as well.

Comment: I agree with your explaination... but why maven build is not giving error? I am using jdk1.7.0_67 to compile. its not giving any error. it compiles fine.